# Configuring Nginx to Act as a Proxy for Various Websites

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a domain as example https://jon.com
When I make a request from jon.com to https://live.jon.com/https://awebsitewhichneedstobeproxied.com
I would like the live.jon.com (where is the nginx) to serve https://awebsitewhichneedstobeproxied.com proxied.

I would like to serve any website proxied not just https://awebsitewhichneedstobeproxied.com.

And also I want to strict live.jon.com to accept only requests from jon.com.

How to achieve this with nginx?

I've tried several nginx configs with no success. I do not have any idea now. I brain is frozen.